# Calender week of the year

Tags: bash, shell

In a bash script I want to spend the number of calendar weeks.

```
date +%G returns the year 2018  
date +%V returns the current week of the current year
```

For example, I need for the calendar year

```
2018 = 52 calendar weeks
2017 = 52 calendar weeks
2016 = 52 calendar weeks
2015 = 53 calendar weeks
```

Is there a simple command to calculate the calendar weeks.
I need the number of last week(s) of the year(s) 2000, 2001, 2002, ..., 2018

Comment: I can see that you've asked **17** questions so far and haven't accepted a single answer. Please take a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Todays week number is

```
date +%U
> 36
```

Comment: I need the number of last week of the year(s) 2000, 2001, 2002, ..., 2018

Comment: The question is not answerd, but is has a solved flag.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Simple command would be

```
date -d 20151231 +'%V'
```

Which gives 53 for 2015. Just loop the year.

Comment: It doesn't work for several years in mentioned range. For example output of `date -d 20021231 +'%V'` is `01`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hacky but if you supply date with the last day of the year for the year in question you can do the following:

```
date -j -f "%m %d %Y" "12 31 2014" +%U 
>> 52
```

Which does the following, parses the format given "%m %d %Y" -> month / day / year which is given in the second set of quotes and then you can use whatever parsing mechanism you want on that. So using that with the "+%U" should give you the number of weeks for the given year.

Answer (score 0):

`ncal` is a tool for displaying the calendar.

Calling `ncal` (or `cal`) displays the current months' calendar.

Call `ncal -w` to also display the week numbers.

Call `ncal 2018` to display all months of year 2018 (others if you want).

Call `ncal 12 2017` to display the calender of december 2017.

Lots of other options - see the [manual](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ncal&sektion=1&n=1).

Example:

```
$ ncal -w -3
    August 2018       September 2018    October 2018      
Su     5 12 19 26        2  9 16 23 30     7 14 21 28   
Mo     6 13 20 27        3 10 17 24     1  8 15 22 29   
Tu     7 14 21 28        4 11 18 25     2  9 16 23 30   
We  1  8 15 22 29        5 12 19 26     3 10 17 24 31   
Th  2  9 16 23 30        6 13 20 27     4 11 18 25      
Fr  3 10 17 24 31        7 14 21 28     5 12 19 26      
Sa  4 11 18 25        1  8 15 22 29     6 13 20 27      
   31 32 33 34 35    35 36 37 38 39 40 40 41 42 43 44   
$
```